# Django: Calling a model's function in my template - not working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to call a function from my model (check_nick) in my template. It appears that the template is successfully hitting the function since the items in the function are printed. However I'm not getting the expected result (True) as the user.group I'm testing with is NICK which is part of the NICK_BRANDS list.

MODEL.PY:

```
NICK_BRANDS = ['NICK', 'NICKT', 'NICKN', 'NICKK', 'NICKA']


class User():

    group = models.ForeignKey(Brand, null=True, blank=True)

    def check_nick(self):
        brand = self.group
        print brand  //prints NICK
        print brand in NICK_BRANDS  //prints False (should be True!)
        if brand in NICK_BRANDS:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

TEMPLATE:

```
 {% if user.check_nick %}
    //add some markup
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your debug prints some string representation of `brand`, but you are checking the actual object. Change your if-clause to sth like:

```
 if str(brand) in NICK_BRANDS:
 # if brand.title in NICK_BRANDS:
 # if brand.name in NICK_BRANDS:
 # or whatever field of Brand is "NICK"
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.group` will be an instance of the related `Brand` model, not a string, and hence would probably not return True with the `in` statement.  I presume there is some `Brand.name` property and you should be using:

```
def check_nick(self):
    return self.group.name in NICK_BRANDS
```